# I get a "could not create lock file" error when trying to run Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I recently had to replace my postgresql.conf file, and I thought I got the settings right, but when I try to run Postgresql, I get this error:

```
 ESTFATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
```

My workaround is to go as root and create a folder called postgresql in /var/run and then change the owner of the folder to postgres.

The biggest problem is that I need to do this every single time my computer starts, the folder somehow deletes itself.

I tried commenting out the external pid file bit in the conf file, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Which distro are you running? Post the init script `/etc/init.d/postgresql`?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu, the init script is the one that comes with postgresql, Postgresql used to run on startup, but now it doesn't. I am guessing that the script encounters the same error as above. Where can I go and check startup errors?

Answer (score 1):

- What version of postgresql are you running?
- What repo is it from?
- Can you post your config file and init script?

> I tried commenting out the external pid file bit in the conf file, but that didn't change anything.

Try having it write the pid file out to /var/run/FILE instead of /var/run/postgresql/FILE.

[Edit 1]:

The default socket directories for apps are usually /tmp as it's world writable (which var isn't, of course creating the directory and setting permissions allows this to work, it's rather non-standard and might be better using the standard settings).  Also, I'd leave the extra pid line commented out since the init script doesn't use it.

Comment: I am running PG 9.1.  
I seem to have fixed it for the time being. In the conf file, I changed the location of the socket and the pid file from /var/run/postgresql to /var/postgresql. I made the directory postgresql, and set it's owner to postgres.

But, if you are still curious, here is the [config file](http://pastebin.com/tNjF3Cmf) and here is the [init.d script](http://pastebin.com/8JC9qa2y).

Comment: See [Edit 1] above.